# Convert timestamp since epoch to datetime.datetime

Tags: python

I have the following timestamps since epoch:

```
Timestamp
1346114717972
1354087827000
```

How can I convert these timestamps to some specific output format, e.g., `mm/dd/yyyy hr:min:sec`?

I have tried to convert them to `datetime.datetime` but it failed:

```
 >>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1346114717972)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform time_t
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What you did is correct, just that you're passing milliseconds not seconds. Try `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1346114717972/1000)`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I would use the `time` module

```
>>> import time
>>> time.gmtime(1346114717972/1000.)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2012, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=28, tm_hour=0, tm_min=45, tm_sec=17, tm_wday=1, tm_yday=241, tm_isdst=0)
```

This shows the timestamp in UTC/GMT time.

The timestamp is divided by 1000 as the stamps you have provided are in **milliseconds** since the epoch, not seconds.

Then use `strftime` to format like so:

```
>>> time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',  time.gmtime(1346114717972/1000.))
'08/28/2012 00:45:17'
```

Comment: Phew ... I was assuming seconds so and I calculated that was something like 42685 years since the epoch and I was thinking that something had to be wrong there...

Comment: maybe using `1e3` instead of `1000.` is better

Comment: @zhangxaochen It's the same, right? They are the same float values. But sure, if somebody have forgotten the dot after the 1000 in Python 2, then it was an integer division, and there can be at most one second difference. But it is not the case any more in Python 3.

Answer (score 62):

Assuming millisecond resolution:

```
import datetime

s = '1346114717972'
fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

# local time
t = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(s)/1000.)
print t.strftime(fmt) # prints 2012-08-28 02:45:17

# utc time
t_utc = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(s)/1000.)
print t_utc.strftime(fmt) # prints 2012-08-28 00:45:17
```

Have a look at the documentation for the [`strftime()` and `strptime()` behavior](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Comment: Note that this answer will convert the timestamp to a local datetime. If you want the equivalent datetime in UTC use datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp() instead of datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp().

Answer (score 5):

This is the simplest method I've ever seen-

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
>>> print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S %Z',time.localtime(time.time())))
2018-05-02T13:21:44 IST
```