# converting a JS Date to a Python date object

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

So I'm doing some `Ajax` trickery in the front page, and in the `DJango` backend, I send a JS Object, using `AJAX`... 
the format is: `'Tue Jan 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)'`
So I'm trying to convert it to a Python object:

```
     import datetime
 81    if request.is_ajax():
 82       datestr = request.POST['from_date']
 83       date = datetime.datetime.strptime(datestr, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ").date()
 84       message = date.__str__()
 85    else:
 86       message = "Not Ajax"
 87 
 88    return HttpResponse(message)
```

However I'm getting the following error:

```
time data 'Tue Jan 28 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

How could I fix that?
I'm looking forward a nicer solution that would avoid splitting and parsing the string ...

Comment: do you have an option to change the date format sent? If yes, I would say change it to epoch..

Comment: @Kiran how? I could easily parse the string, but I'm trying to avoid it

Comment: @mhlester not a duplicate ... problems are similar, but different

Comment: sorry you're right. retracted

Comment: I am not fully aware of how python works, but in javascript, you can get epoch by calling date.getTime()/1000. This answer `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458595/convert-epoch-timestamp-in-python` talks about converting epoch to needed format. I thought  you have date object in your javascript based on what you are receiving.

Comment: @Kiran—good approach, but the javascript epoch is 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. *getTime* returns a [time value](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) that is milliseconds since the epoch.

Comment: @RobG that is correct. that's the reason I mentioned date.getTime()/1000. However, looks like python datetime is also taking in milliseconds in which case /1000 may not even be needed

Answer (score 2):

Given the format in the error message, then the client you can use ES5s [Date.prototype.toISOString()](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.43) to convert a Date object to an ISO 8601 string. You'll need a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) for browsers that don't have it.