# Search for the latest rows in terms of timestamp

Tags: python, hadoop, hbase, nutch, happybase

I am looking for how to search for the latest rows in hbase table that is loaded by Nutch 2.3.

I use happybase and thrift, the only example I have found is in this link https://happybase.readthedocs.io/en/happybase-0.4/tutorial.html#using-table-namespaces

Comment: Hi @Hakim My answer was useful? did you find any thing else apart from ?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know python so Im explaining this in hbase shell..
More or less you should be able to do this in python.

#### Python way : [Convert timestamp since epoch to datetime.datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458595/convert-timestamp-since-epoch-to-datetime-datetime)

> #### How to get latest timestamp to pass in the filter ?
>
> LOG data to timestamp
> To convert the date '08/08/16 20:56:29' from an hbase log into a
> timestamp, do:

```
     hbase(main):021:0> import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
                   hbase(main):022:0> import java.text.ParsePosition
                    hbase(main):023:0> SimpleDateFormat.new("yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").parse("08/08/16 20:56:29", ParsePosition.new(0)).getTime()
 => 1218920189000
```

after above you can try something like this:

```
scan 't1', {COLUMNS => 'c1', TIMERANGE => [1303668804, 1303668904]}


hbase(main):001:0> scan
```

Here is some help for this command:
Scan a table; pass table name and optionally a dictionary of scanner
specifications.  Scanner specifications may include one or more of:
TIMERANGE, FILTER, LIMIT, STARTROW, STOPROW, TIMESTAMP, MAXLENGTH,
or COLUMNS, CACHE

#### Some examples:

```
  hbase> scan '.META.'
  hbase> scan '.META.', {COLUMNS => 'info:regioninfo'}
  hbase> scan 't1', {COLUMNS => ['c1', 'c2'], LIMIT => 10, STARTROW => 'xyz'}
  hbase> scan 't1', {COLUMNS => 'c1', TIMERANGE => [1303668804, 1303668904]}
  hbase> scan 't1', {FILTER => "(PrefixFilter ('row2') AND (QualifierFilter (>=, 'binary:xyz'))) AND (TimestampsFilter ( 123, 456))"}
  hbase> scan 't1', {FILTER => org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.ColumnPaginationFilter.new(1, 0)}
```

Comment: but I can't have happybase use timerange because its not supported

Comment: Hakim : there is something called timestamp filter in happybase?

Comment: Hakim I think in this syntax (`scan(row_start=None, row_stop=None, row_prefix=None, columns=None, filter=None, timestamp=None, include_timestamp=False, batch_size=1000, scan_batching=None, limit=None, sorted_columns=False`) you can pass filter which are related to happybase isnt it ? [pls check](http://happybase.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)

Comment: My answer was useful?  did you find any thing else apart from ?

Comment: Sorry for being late, The timestamp filter use a unique timestamp value, can't use timerange.