# How to extract Google PubSub publish time in Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My goal is to be able to access PubSub message Publish Time as recorded and set by Google PubSub in Apache Beam (Dataflow).

```
    PCollection<PubsubMessage> pubsubMsg
            = pipeline.apply("Read Messages From PubSub",
            PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes()
                .fromSubscription(pocOptions.getInputSubscription()));
```

Does not seem to contain one as an attribute.
I have tried

```
 .withTimestampAttribute("publish_time")
```

No luck either. What am I missing? Is it possible to extract Google PubSub publish time in dataflow?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Java version**:

PubsubIO will read the message from Pub/Sub and assign the message publish time to the element as the record timestamp. Therefore, you can access it using [`ProcessContext.timestamp()`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.14.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.ProcessContext.html). As an example:

```java
p
    .apply("Read Messages", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription(subscription))
    .apply("Log Publish Time", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, Void>() {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
            LOG.info("Message: " + c.element());
            LOG.info("Publish time: " + c.timestamp().toString());
            Date date= new Date();
            Long time = date.getTime();
            LOG.info("Processing time: " + new Instant(time).toString());
        }
    }));
```

I published a message a little bit ahead (to have a significant difference between event and processing time) and output with DirectRunner was:

```java
Mar 27, 2019 11:03:08 AM com.dataflow.samples.LogPublishTime$1 processElement
INFO: Message: I published this message a little bit before
Mar 27, 2019 11:03:08 AM com.dataflow.samples.LogPublishTime$1 processElement
INFO: Publish time: 2019-03-27T09:57:07.005Z
Mar 27, 2019 11:03:08 AM com.dataflow.samples.LogPublishTime$1 processElement
INFO: Processing time: 2019-03-27T10:03:08.229Z
```

Minimal code [here](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/365eb6587ab6007da421b23d3ae79440)

---

**Python version**:

Now the timestamp can be accessed through `DoFn.TimestampParam` of the `process` method ([docs](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.14.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.DoFn.process)):

```py
class GetTimestampFn(beam.DoFn):
  """Prints element timestamp"""
  def process(self, element, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam):
    timestamp_utc = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(timestamp))
    logging.info(">>> Element timestamp: %s", timestamp_utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    yield element
```

*Note*: date parsing thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12458763/6121516).

Output:

```py
INFO:root:>>> Element timestamp: 2019-08-12 20:16:53
```

Full [code](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/c0753bff5e5883791f4c2de7e0689562)

Comment: Would also like to thank you specifically for the code sample. Made it super easy to implement. Kudos!

Comment: Nice, I'm happy I was able to help

Comment: I'm programming in python and I can't find the equivalent of Process context.

Comment: Sure, @Rim. I have edited my original answer to add the Python equivalent too!

Comment: Excellent answer with great detail and shared code! Thanks!! :)