# Pubsub message is missing a timestamp attribute

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to read the timestamp value of a Pubsub message from Apache Beam.

```
p.apply("Read PubSub messages", PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes()
    .withIdAttribute("msg_id")
    .withTimestampAttribute("timestamp")
    .fromSubscription(options.getPubsubSubscription()))
```

But unfortunately, I got the following error which really surprises me as I thought every messages had a default timestamp.

```
An exception occured while executing the Java class. 
PubSub message is missing a value for timestamp attribute timestamp
```

Why is my message not timestamped ? Is it because I published it via the Pubsub UI ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every Pub/Sub message will have default timestamps assigned if you omit `.withTimestampAttribute()`. When you add `.withTimestampAttribute("timestamp")` it implies that you will be providing the timestamps in the `timestamp` attribute of each message. For example, using the UI:

[image]

Then, windowing will be relative to these timestamps and, if you need to access it from within the pipeline, you can use [`ProcessContext.timestamp()`](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.12.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.ProcessContext.html) (more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55374648/6121516)).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! It seems you're right. I was a bit disturbed because I thought it was the opposite way of working. Also, there's no method (yet) to retrieve the messageId from a PubsubMessage if not explicitly set with attributes https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-3489 :(